# How to change TabBarItem style or cancel default function (Xamarin forms iOS and Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In my case, my tabbar items are Navigation Pages which in some cases may or may not be in a stack, ie it may be that the current page of this stack is not the first Page, the default function of tabbar item takes me straight. for the first item in this stack, which is very bad for my users.

Is it possible to modify this? Cancel navigation when you click on the tabbar item or something that solves this problem?

Alternatively, I was implementing a CustomRenderer that turned off (Enable = false) in UITabBarItem, it works but changes the style and this is not cool in my case, I tried in many ways to override the Disable state and could not.

Comment: can you please post code that illustrates the problem?  Switching tabs should not affect the Navigation stack within each tab

Comment: @Jason If you are already on the desired tab and click again (this child being a navigation and not on the first page) it returns to the first page of the stack.

Comment: @Jason in my case this cannot happen.*

Comment: maybe  you could try to write custom  render to capture Tab selection events for modification